# Angularjs service to populate options from get request with processing

Tags: json, angularjs, populate, get-request

I have a service in angular js. In this service I have a method that generates a get request against a json input.

On the results I want to do some processing on the json response and then return the processed values.  The processed values would then be populated as select options.

The issue im having is that it does not populate the select options.

[I have a plunker that has it almost working](http://plnkr.co/edit/cBoF5gVF3iX8dplMTu9Z?p=preview).

**angular-app.js**

```
angular.module('my.app', []);

angular.module('my.app').controller('DemoCtrl', [ 'DemoService', function(DemoService) {

  self = this;  
  self.chooseCountryGroups=DemoService.getCountryGroups()

}]);
```

**angular-service.js**

```
angular.module('my.app')

  .factory('DemoService', ['$http', function($http) {
          return {
              getCountryGroups: function() {
                  dataResults = [];

                  // do some processing on json response  (return only the keys)
                  $http.get('country-groups.json').success(function(data){

                      for(var countryCountryName in data){
                        dataResults.push(countryCountryName);
                      } 
                      //console.log(dataResults);  looks ok on log output
                  });
                  return dataResults;
              }        
          }
  }])
```

**html**

```
<html ng-app="my.app">

<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demoCtrl">
    <select id="country" name="country" style="width: 200px" size=5 
            ng-model="demoCtrl.filterOptions.countryGroup"
            ng-options="country as country for country in demoCtrl.chooseCountryGroup">
    </select>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/19U8IfCfAOnAaVgI8UM9?p=preview

Comment: What exactly is the issue after your last comment?

Comment: thanks Naeem - how did you fix it.. im looking at the code and I cant seem to see it?

Comment: found it I miss typed `demoCtrl.chooseCountryGroup` when it should have been `demoCtrl.chooseCountryGroups`

Comment: Please leave an answer and mark it solved to help others in the future.